# How to integrate a CMS into an existing website

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, xampp

If you were to integrate some open source CMS into your already existing website... which CMS would you choose and how would you go about achieving it?

Comment: Depends very much on your requirements. Every CMS has its own niche features. 
Also, depending on size/complexity/structure of your website, it might be easier to think in terms of "integrating your website into an open source CMS".

Comment: I want a very lightweight CMS built in PHP. Any idea?

Comment: go for modx or wordpress dependent of your php skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should ask the question in different order "How to migrate already existing content to open source CMS" and your action list would be

1. map existing data and url schema (so you could make redirects from old content to new locations if locations change) to get the hang of the amount of pages/structure that need conversion
2. choose your next weapon (wordpress, joomla, modx and so on dependent of your needs and amount of data) and make a clean installation of latest version
3. convert old site information to data import format of your chosen weapon
4. if your information is in start planning design, editorial and other regular tasks that each site needs

the idea here is to make the conversion first with raw data to get the clean site structure and content you really need and not mess with design and editorial tasks first as those are secondary and can be addressed separately over and over

Answer (score 5):

The BEST CMSs that will work very well and may fit your needs are :

1. [Instante Update](http://www.cubescripts.com/cms-script.php) - the best one in my opinion
2. [PulseCMS](http://www.PulseCMS.com)
3. [SiteCake](http://www.SiteCake.com)

These three CMSs can be integrated into any existing Website & they are easy to use. I  think they fit your needs.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, as it indeed answers the question !

Answer (score 0):

i would go with wordpress... just download in from wordpress.org and install it into ur site, via FTP or File Manager, but you need to know how to use wordpress, everything would be very basic in PHP, they usually slice the website into three parts. Header, Body, and Footer, try to mess with it, and you could integrate it... but i think CMS is much preferrable if ur trying to create a blog-style website

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider the popularity of the Open Source platform you choose. The more popular it is, the less likely it will disappear all of a sudden - and it will be a lot easier to get community support (and 3rd party modules).

For me there would be 3 choices if it has to be a PHP based CMS : Wordpress, Joomla or Drupal. I tend to prefer the latter, because it's very flexible (though it also has some quirks, especially if you're creating multilangual sites).

As for how to go about it : that largely depends on what you already have. Is it a static site or dynamic site? Have you got some scripts that wouldn't be easy to alter? Your first priority should be to list specific functionalities of your site and see if any of the CMSes you consider supports these out-of-the-box (or using 3rd party modules).

Porting data to Drupal can be very easy (using the Migrate module - [Migration: not just for the birds](http://dc2009.drupalcon.org/session/migration-not-just-birds)).

Oh, and one more thing : also keep things you plan for the future in mind. If you consider building a full blown website, don't stick with something that will help you out now, but hold you back in the future.

Comment: people who suggest Drupal as a development platform are clearly under influence of drugs or alcohol :)

Comment: I'm not going to say that Drupal is the be-all and end-all of CMSes - there's a lot of room for improvement - but it does have some major benefits (a very large userbase, lots of 3rd party modules - ok there's utter crap between them, but that goes for every CMS out there). btw I'm mixing Zend Framework legacy code with Drupal, guess what I like best (hint: it doesn't start with a D :p).